# Is RestHighLevelClient keep connections open?

Tags: elasticsearch, resthighlevelclient, elasticsearch-rest-client

I want to use `RestHighLevelClient` on different clusters with commands which are not supported by Cross Cluster mechanizem (for example close and open index). 
My question is if I use more than one instance of `RestHighLevelClient` for every cluster it will keep connections open for every cluster? (to be ensure I didn't choke the application)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

by looking at various resources, it seems `RestHighLevelClient` keeps the connection open unless you explicitly call `client.close();` on it.

From the  [official RestHighLevelClient initialization](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high-getting-started-initialization.html)

> The high-level client will internally create the low-level client used
> to perform requests based on the provided builder. That low-level
> client maintains a pool of connections and starts some threads **so you
> should close the high-level client when you are well and truly done
> with it and it will in turn close the internal low-level client to
> free those resources.** This can be done through the close method:

In your case, if you having a lot of ES clusters and creating multiple `RestHighLevelClient` than as you are guessing, it might choke your application due to the hold of threads and its resources so you should explicitly call the `close` which would require more time when you again create it but would not choke your application in most of the cases.

I would suggest you do some resource benchmarking on your application and based on your trade-off choose the best possible approach.

1. Create multiple clients and don't close them but allocate more resources so that the application is fast and don't choke.
2. `close` clients frequently, this would not require over-allocating resources but when you create a new client for your request, latency will be more.